# Best approach for multiple versioned WSDLs

Tags: spring-integration

We have a web service that contains 6 different service endpoints, and thus 6 different WSDLs.  We are using spring integration for the underlying infrastructure.  This particular project will support multiple versions, which is working correctly.

From what I understand, I can server WSDLs one of three ways:

```
> - <static-wsdl>
> - <dynamic-wsdl>
> - custom servlet approach
```

The first two approaches do not scale well, I would have to add a new set of WSDL definitions for each version and since the id specifies the WSDL location, the user would have to access something like service1_v1.wsdl, service1_v2.wsdl, etc.  For example, here is what the config would look like for static wsdls for two versions:

```
<sws:static-wsdl id="service1_v1" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v1/service1.wsdl"/>
<sws:static-wsdl id="service2_v1" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v2/service2.wsdl"/>
...
<sws:static-wsdl id="service1_v2" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v2/service1.wsdl"/>
<sws:static-wsdl id="service2_v2" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v2/service2.wsdl"/>
...
<sws:static-wsdl id="service1_v3" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v3/service1.wsdl"/>
<sws:static-wsdl id="service2_v3" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/v3/service2.wsdl"/>
```

The last approach would involve a servlet that processed any wsdl requests, and using a request parameter determine the version.  However, I will not be able to take adavantage of any built in spring functionality, like transformLocations.

Is it possible to generate WSDLs programatically?  I could add a maven task to generate the WSDLs and add the spring beans at startup.

What I am trying to avoid is having a lot of config and having to update this config every time that we add a new version or deprecate one.  I already have a mechanism in SI to correctly router the messages to the appropriate versioned endpoint, just need to finalize the WSDL mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it programmatically, using the same classes that the `MessageDispatcherServlet` uses, as [documented in the Spring Web Services Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure).

Note, however, the `caution` there about dynamically creating WSDLs.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I was not more clear.  I would like to generate the WSDLs programatically with some sort of build, check them in once before release to production, then create the static-wsdl beans in code as well.  The intent is to minimize the large amount of configuration we would have to do to map the WSDLs.  We currently are using dynamic-wsdl, however this is only for development purposes due to the risk involved.  At the end of the day, I don't want to have to update multiple sections of our configuration for a new version, adding the wsdl declaration each time complicates that issue.